# Displaying the recurrence window of Appointmentitems

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am currently working on a VSTO Outlook Addin, that uses a custom WPF-form to gather user inputs and transfer them to an Appointmentitem in background. Everything works great, but now I have realized, that I want to give the users the option to make the appointment they are creating recurring.

Ideally Id want to **display the recurrence window that Appointmentitems offer by default**, without displaying the actual Appointmentitem. So when a button on my custom form gets clicked it should open the recurrence window.

I have looked into RecurrencePattern objects and AppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern, but I didn't find anything that's useful for my problem.

Do you guys know of a way I could implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for displaying the recurrence settings UI/dialog separately, like shown below:

[image: recurrence pattern settings dialog]

You need to create such dialogs on your own.

Or, as a possible workaround, you may consider creating a form region where you could display your custom WPF UI and keep working the Fluent UI along with your custom UI. See [Create Outlook form regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions?view=vs-2022) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to show that dialog unless you also show the appointment inspector and simulate a click on the corresponding ribbon button.